# Difference between node.js command promt and .exe

Tags: node.js

I am sorry if this is a really generic question, however I've looked around and can't seem to find an answer.

I'm running `node.js` on Windows, and it has 2 things installed, `Nodejs.exe` and `Node.js` command prompt. I have gotten the script running with the command prompt, but I cannot figure out what the exe version does. The `--debug` flag which I want to use seems to only work on the exe. It seems it works similar to the python idle where you can type `d = 6`, then `d` and get the number 6 back, however I can't find anything else that it does.

Could somebody help explain what it is for? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two shortcuts provided when installing NodeJS on Windows:

[image: Node applications installed on Windows]

1. **Node.js** = this is a captive shell for testing and executing JavaScript code. It's the same as if you typed `node` from a command prompt (assuming the `node.exe` is in the path). It's great for simple tests (and I often use it as a calculator).
2. **Node.js command prompt** = this is a standard command prompt where the path has been adjusted to include `node.exe` (the NodeJS executable) along with `npm`, the Node Package Manager. In a default install though, the NodeJS directories are added to the system path, so `node` should be available from any command prompt.

So, using the command prompt (#2), you can use it to start scripts for example:

```
node app.js
```

Where `app.js` is the NodeJS code you've written.

As I mentioned though, `node` and `npm` are normally in the system path, so I don't use the two shortcuts. Instead, I just start a new command prompt:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. `cmd` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. `node` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Kind of a late comment, but did you mean a "restricted shell"? I looked up "captive shell" and couldn't find much, but restricted shell came up.

Comment: @Natalie - no, I did not. Captive accounts are used in *nix operating systems -- not as frequently in Windows. Same idea though. A shell executable program that is launched directly -- when exited, the shell exits too. I don't know that there's a better name for it in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the Node executable without any arguments, you are opening a [REPL session](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

A REPL - short for "[Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)" - is used in different ways, depending upon the language/system it supports.  Often, though, you'll find it most useful when you are:

- Learning the system and want to test how fundamental concepts are implemented within the system.  (Example: performing simple file system activities)
- Testing an idea or exploring a problem with code, using an interactive environment so results can very quickly be viewed. (example: load a small bit of code your wrote and call it to view the output interactively as you tweak)

While a REPL can be useful when testing specific (and typically simple) matters, the REPL bogs down when things get more complex.  As such, the REPL should be understood in the larger context of the Node ecosystem that includes tools like [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) and a healthy suite of TDD options that can successfully be used to explore and test more complicated designs/problems.